# Calculating Test Strength from the XML output, what does 'detected' represent?

Tags: java, pitest

I am attempting to calculate the Test Strength generated by the HTML output from the data within the XML output of PIT however the figure I calculate doesn't align with the Test Strength from the HTML report.

I use the equation `(mutationsKilled / (totalMutations - mutationsNotCovered) * 100)`, where:

- `mutationsKilled` was generated by counting the entries where `status = "KILLED"`
- `totalMutations` was generated by counting the total entries
- `mutationsNotCovered` was generated by counting the entries where `detected = "false"`

However, it's the last of these that I suspect could be the problem, as when looking back at the raw XML output I find that detected metric may not necessarily indicate whether the mutation was covered or not.

Is there a tried and tested way of doing this? Also may be worth mentioning I'm running PIT 1.9.4 and also the incremental analysis mode, if this has any bearing on the issue.

Comment: Tags do not belong in question titles. Please don't revert my edit again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting and intentionally reducing my test coverage to produce uncovered mutants, I found that there is a possible status, `NO_COVERAGE`. By adjusting the above equation to generate `mutationsNotCovered` by counting the entries where `status = "NO_COVERAGE"`, the correct statistics are produced.

Comment: This will still be incorrect as you are not accounting for statuses such as TIMED_OUT. Pitest will set detected = 'true' for all mutant it believes a test can detect. I would suggest using this in place of checking for status = "KILLED"

Comment: Makes sense @henry, to clarify: mutationsKilled uses detected='true', totalMutations counts all mutations in the file and mutationsNotCovered uses status = 'NO_COVERAGE'. Using the equations above and these definitions will produce test strength. I appreciate your help.